# Codeigniter webhost client-side ajax error (deny 501)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Hi currently im watching my website showing the info if my IP is on whitelist in my webhost if it doesn't, then it wont get the news or load correctly php/JS.

The reason for this happen is the following but idk if some of you have had this before and if is an http request function missing or some protocol of server-sides (common one).

Error from server-side :

```
[client ip ... ] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 501 (phase 2).
 Match of "rx ^((?:(?:POS|GE)T|OPTIONS|HEAD))$" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. 
[file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] 
[line "38"]
[id "1234123435"] 
[msg "Method is not allowed by policy"] 
[severity "CRITICAL"] 
[tag "POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"] 
[hostname "link"]
[uri "/showTopNews"] 
[unique_id "WVukp1ka8AEAChYSbGQAAAAP"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a `mod_security2` error. More specifically, caused by rule `1234123435`

Seems you're violating the `REQUEST_METHOD` regex. The accepted request types are `POST`, `GET`, `OPTIONS`, `HEAD`.

You have a few options:

1) fix the request type in your code (use a type that is allowed - open Developer Tools and watch the Newtork tab to see what you're sending)

2) update your rule to allow other types as well (not extremely dangerous if you know what you're adding)

3) You can remove the rule altogether by using this in your apache vhost `.conf` file (it won't work in `.htaccess`):

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRuleRemoveById 1234123435
</IfModule>
```

I'd go with the first one.

The limitation to those 4 request types is fairly reasonable. But it does exclude some types. See [HTTP/Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) for more details

Comment: hi thx for the info, the only ways im using for this are ajax type not even post, get, etc just using type: ajax and it denys

Comment: hi. "ajax" isn't a method type :) Give this a read [SO: What exactly is Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130239/what-is-exactly-is-ajax-request-is-it-different-from-servlet-request)

Comment: nah i didnt mean it is a request type, i just meant that in http type of requesting to my server-side, i'm not using post or get i'm just using ajax(the standart one).