# call php from javascript with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, href

First, I'm very new to php so be comprehensive :) So, I have an issue with some php/JS code. What I'm trying to achieve is to execute code from a php file with JS code by using ajax.

I have a calendar with href link so navigate to previous/next month. It's working well and It was asked to add a combobox to select month without using previous/next. So I used ajax to call a new file I created but for some reason, page is reloading when I call my new file with href, but It doesn't with ajax. Here is my code :

JS -->

```
function changeMonth() {
    var select_months = document.getElementById('select_months');
    var value = select_months.options[select_months.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'previousMonth.php?',
        data: {
            mois: value
        },
        success: function(output) {
            console.info(output);
        },
        error: function(output) {
            console.info(output);
        }
    });
}
```

php ->

```
<?php     
    session_start();

    $page = null;
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $year = null;
    if (isset($_SESSION['annee'])) {
        $year = $_SESSION['annee'];
    } else {
        $year = date("Y");
    }

    $month = null;
    if (isset($_POST['mois'])) {
        $month = $_POST['mois'];
    } else {
        $month = date("m");
    }

    $_SESSION['mois'] = 6;
    $_SESSION['annee'] = $year;

    header('location: ' . $page);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mois pr�c�dent</title>      
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that I can reach the file because html code was modified. But, what I cannot understand is that my page doesn't reload, so data are not updated.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: "what I cannot understand is that my page doesn't reload" — That's the **point** of Ajax. If you want to load a new page when you make the HTTP request: Don't use Ajax! Use a normal form submission.

Comment: Although not precisely a dupe, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130251/3757232) will probably answer your question.

Comment: Ajax is meant to not reaload the page. You can execute your code with ajax and then pass back the result. Based on that result, you replace with javascript the data you want to.

Comment: Ah, ok. So that's why I can reach my php code but data are not updated. How can I do that when a value is selected in my combobox?

Comment: You need to look in the console log to see the return from php, that is what your `success` function is doing. That is where you handle the returned data