# Trying to render my ejs file from a node backend after clicking a delete button - without using ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a simple blog application using node.js for backend and ejs for frontend. I am able to post blogs, using a web form with an input type submit, calling a post route. This works fine. But now I am trying to implement a delete button for each post. The only way I have found to make a button (outside the form) work with node, is using ajax and fetch, like this:

This registers the button click and triggers the delete function, but creates the problem that the page does not render when I try to send the response: res.render(path.resolve("views/index.ejs"), data); Which is apparently how ajax works.
I have found out that it's possible to do this without using ajax, using jquery with node, which is also possible but not straight forward, and I don´t know how to.

I am an **absolute** beginner in node and ejs, so any help is very welcome!
(P.S: I tried including my code in this question, but the page insists tells me it's not properly formatted and won't let me..)

Pressing the delete button triggers the /delete route and the delete function, but does not render the page.

Comment: `Ajax` means, Loading a web resource asynchronously without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. It either can be done with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Both are features of JavaScript. On the other hand, `Jquery` is a Javascript Library, It still uses javascript features behind the scenes. So what do you mean by **I have found out that it's possible to do this without using ajax, using jquery** ?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for being imprecise. What I am trying to say is that if I use ajax when the button is clicked to trigger my /delete route, then it seems the ejs-page will not be rendered again. So I probably (?) need to use jquery when the button is clicked to trigger the /delete, but how to that it when using node.js for backend?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean with

> I have found out that it's possible to do this without using ajax, using jquery with node...

but I think you're misunderstanding AJAX requests.
An AJAX request (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) is an asynchronous request from the browser (client) to the server. 99% usage for AJAX requests is to handle data (retrieving, posting, removing, ...) in the background of an application, but it **does not directly result in a page transition**. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130239/what-exactly-is-ajax-request-is-it-different-from-servlet-request) question for more detailed explanations.

When making an AJAX request, anything besides the handling of the data will be done in the EJS/HTML file.

Let's look at a small example, using the express framework:

`someView.ejs`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- set up html page -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <button onclick="getData()">Get some Data</button>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Hi! My name is Dave</p>
      <p>Today I am 25 years old</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function getData() {
        fetch('/data/get', {method: 'GET', headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'} })
        .then( raw_data => raw_data.json() )
        .then( data => {
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = 
            `<p>Hi! My name is ${data.name}</p>` +
            `<p>Today I am ${data.age} years old</p>`
        })
        .catch( err => console.log(err) )
      }
    </script>

  </body>
<html>
```

`main.js`

```js
// imports and app configuration

app.get('/data/get', (req, res) => {
  // get data from database/memory, internally from the server, etc. We will use mock data
  const data = {name: "Johnny", age: 52};
  res.send(data);
})
```

The page will render with a button and the text inside the `<div>`

```html
<button onclick="getData()">Get some Data</button>
<div id="content">
  <p>Hi! My name is Dave</p>
  <p>Today I am 25 years old</p>
</div>
```

Now, if you click on the button (not here on the code snippet, as we don't have a nodejs server here), the browser will make a fetch request to the server. On the server we handle the data, which in our case consists of the name and age of Johnny. Any kind of response, be it `res.send(...)` or `res.render(...)`, will not make the page of the browser load that data. Instead, you will get the data from the fetch call, either inside a `then()` function (like in the example) or if using async/await syntax it would be something like `let raw_data = await fetch(...).catch(...)`. There you can then further work with the data, like in our example, we change the innerHTML of the div. So after pressing the button it would look like this:

```html
<button onclick="getData()">Get some Data</button>
<div id="content">
  <p>Hi! My name is Johnny</p>
  <p>Today I am 52 years old</p>
</div>
```

In most use cases, you want to then change the DOM based on the data retrieved, like we did. But obviously, you shouldn't hard-code the HTML as I have in this example. Rather, you would create a partial to render with a set of data.

`person.ejs`

```html
<p>Hi! My name is <%= person.name %><</p>
<p>Today I am <%= person.age %> years old</p>
```

Now you need to get this file in `someView.ejs` to render it. The easiest way probably is to do another fetch request on the file:

```
fetch('/views/partials/person.ejs')
.then( raw_data => raw_data.text())
.then( data => {
  const html = ejs.render(data, {name: 'Brian', age: 40});
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;
})
```

But, to use the ejs variable on the client side, you need to download either `ejs.js` or `ejs.min.js` from [the github](https://github.com/mde/ejs/releases) and add it like this `<script src="path/to/file/ejs.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` (For more help on this, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001619/client-side-and-server-side-rendering-of-ejs-template) question or ask me in the comments).

All that's left is combining all the things I explained here together. Good luck!